# Raphael JS 3D effect drop shadow

Tags: raphael, graphael

I'm trying to make a fairly complex Raphael JS donut graph.

I got several problems, one of them been the 3D effect, which I'm planning to solve by adding 7 drop shadows (glows) or donut duplicates after eachother, to simulate the 7px thickness of the shape.

How could I do this the best way? Thank you in advance...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vedmack/sutLS/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seven shadows don't seem like the best way to do it, because it is computationally expensive, because it won't look nice and because one should generally avoid thinking in terms of pixels when working with vector graphics.

If you want to draw a segment of a cylinder -- draw it. Including the sides. Even with solid colour it will create a reasonable illusion of 3d, and you can make it look nicer by using gradients to simulate lighting. You will have to keep track of which faces are actually visible, but that is the case with pretty much any approach to 3D, including the shadow thing.

Comment: I've Fiddled my PIE here: http://jsfiddle.net/xEYpL/. I want it to become a donut, which I'm struggeling with, and further more, I want to do what you propose - but can you guide me - how??

Comment: It's just a matter of some coding. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/xEYpL/15/ for basic donut rendering. I'm sure you can manage from there on.

Comment: Sure it's a matter of code, somehow it always is... ;-) ... thank you for your donut shape, but I don't understand where to go from here to make the 3d-style rendering of the sides of the donut.

My initial idea was to copy the donut 7 times, but you convinced me otherwise. Can you point me in the right direction?

I only need it to be a solid, darker, color than the top, so nothing fancy. But the math of it seems utterly painful.

Comment: @KennethB I suggest that first you check whether a particular side of the segment is visible at all. If it is, you have to basically duplicate the edge of the segment and shift it down, then add the vertical edges to connect the two.

Comment: I know I'm asking for much, but can you do this for me in my Fiddle? This is my first chart, and my understanding of the approach is very limited, unfortunaly.

Comment: @KennethB stackoverflow is a Q&A website, not oDesk. And I rather think it is a good exercize

Comment: I know, and I'm sorry I had to ask you. I'm just in over my head on this one, and I've spend a week already on this darn thing.

Answer (score 0):

@KennethB Maybe these plugins could help you: https://github.com/bkuzmic/raphael-charts-plugin and https://github.com/PuffyCoffee/3D-Pie-chart. Download these plugins and study the code, these plugins have MIT license and use Raphael.